# Tirar screenshot no meio do vídeo ffmpeg / ffprobe?

Tags: php, vídeo

Eu gostaria que o tempo em que a thumb fosse gerada correspondesse a 50% do tempo do episódio com ffmpeg estou usando esse código

```
$ffmpeg -ss 00:00:18 -i $video -vf scale=800:-1 -vframes 1 $output
```

Como faço para no lugar de 00:00:18, ser o tempo exato no meio do video?

Answer (score 1):

Para pegar um frame no segundo 18:

```
ffmpeg -ss 18 -i video.mp4 -vframes 1 -f image2 frame.jpg
```

Comment: Se precisar salvar em um tamanho diferente adicione o parâmetro -s com a resolução desejada:

`ffmpeg -ss 18 -i video.mp4 -vframes 1 -s 320x240 -f image2 frame.jpg`